# change foundation button into a link

Tags: html, zurb-foundation

I currently have a button from foundation which I want to add a link to but every time that I do this is either removes the button or doesn't link! Obviously I would quite like both to work!
Can someone tell me how I have to add the link to the code for the button below! I know this might sound very elementary but still trying to get used to foundation!

```
<div class="clear10"></div>
            <button class="rounded shadow">Get Started</button>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this should do

```html
<link href="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/foundation/5.4.3/css/foundation.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


     <div class="clear10">
        <a href="your link" class="button rounded shadow">Get Started</a>
     </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here i have given little more flexibility in the code

```
 <div class="clear10">
    <button class="round-button">
     <a href="your link" class="linking">Get Started</a>
    </button>
  </div>
```

css

```
.round-button {
    display:block;
    width:400px;
    height:60px;
    border-radius:20px;
    text-align:center;
    background: #464646; 
}
.round-button:hover {
    background: #262626;
}

.linking{
    font-size:20px;
    font-weight:bold;
    color:#fff!important;
}
```

Try this **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/manjunath_siddappa/29o03Lhk/1/)**

Comment: This is invalid HTML -- you can't nest interactive elements

Comment: @Rudi , i didnt catch your comment, can you please explain more. i found issue one issue, <div> closing early? any other issue? please let me know.